# Division confusion in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am making a Pong game in Delphi.

```
Paddle.Left := X - Paddle.Width div 2;
Paddle.Top := ClientHeight - Paddle.Height - 2;
```

I expect the output of `5/2` to be 2.5, but the actual output is 2.

Comment: 5/2 would yield 2.5, but you did 5 div 2. Read the code once more to see that.

Comment: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/expressions_xml.html#4F70657261746F7273

Comment: While this question may be poor quality and an easy mistake, I don't understand the close vote as "Too Broad".

Answer (score 4):

The `div` operator performs *integer division* (`5 div 2 = 2`, throwing away the decimal `.5`), whereas the `/` operator performs *floating point division* (`5 / 2 = 2.5`).

In VCL, a control's `Left`, `Top`, `Width`, and `Height` values are expressed using whole integers, not floating point numbers.

In FMX, a control's `Position` and `Size` values are expressed using floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

[`div`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operators) is the *integer* division operator. It is a binary operator that takes two integers, and returns an integer, the truncated value of the division. For instance,

```
0 div 3 = 0
1 div 3 = 0
2 div 3 = 0
3 div 3 = 1
4 div 3 = 1
5 div 3 = 1
6 div 3 = 2
...
```

If you want to perform a floating-point division, you need to use the `/` operator:

```
0 / 3 = 0
1 / 3 = 0.33333333333333
2 / 3 = 0.66666666666666
3 / 3 = 1
4 / 3 = 1.33333333333333
5 / 3 = 1.66666666666666
6 / 3 = 2
...
```

Of course, the result cannot be stored in an integer variable. If you eventually need an integer value to specify a pixel on the screen, you need to round the floating-point value to an integer (using the `Round` function).